# What random number generation systems would return exactly one result for a given key?

Tags: c#, c++, random, hash, generator

I am looking for a crossplarform standard random number generator which - after being initialised with a seed - always returns the same random **number** for a given integer key.

And this without generating any kind of key/value maps, memory conservation is way more important than processor usage at this point.

Let's say we initialise the generator with a seed (which is not the key).

Then we can retrieve a result for any arbitrary key. Each call will always return the same result for the same key.

For example:

```
KeyBasedRandomGenerator r1 = new KeyBasedRandomGenerator(MY_SEED);
KeyBasedRandomGenerator r2 = new KeyBasedRandomGenerator(MY_SEED);
int test = r1.Get(500);
for (int key = 0; key < 10000000; ++key)
{
    assert ( r1.Get(key) == r2.Get(key));
}
assert ( r1.Get(500) == test);
```

Is there an implementation which available for C# and C++? What are they called?

Is it possible to find variations which always return the same result for a range:

```
    assert ( r.Get(key, 0, 15) == r.Get(key, 0, 15));
```

---

**Edit**: I Understand the role of hashes and how the usual random generators work. What I am looking is a standardised random number generator function or implementation (library) which works with keys.

If there is no more specific terminology than "hash function" for this scenario then hash it is.

Comment: So just add your own PRNG with source code so you'll always know what results to expect.

Comment: You're looking for a "perfect hash function" --- if your inputs are known beforehand, there are tools to generate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they are called "hash functions". The key doesn't have to be just a single number. It could be any chunk of data. A hash function executes a complex bit-wise calculation on some arbitrary input, and produces a single value for output. For all practical purposes, the resulting hash value will appear random.

Comment: I believe I can put together a solution using a hash function, I was wondering if there wasn't an existing  generic/standard solution that would accomplish this.

Comment: There are multiple standard hash functions. Google food for you: MD5, SHA1, SHA256. I'm sure there's one for C#, and I know of several standard cryptographic libraries that implement these hash functions in C and C++, guaranteeing the same result in both languages, which you indicate is one of your desired features.

Answer (score 1):

LCG, with a good set of parameters for a given space (say, 64bit) will produce the same RN for a given input/state.

Basically, LCG will map any 64bit value uniquely into another 64bit value.

Also, say, decent cipher like AES will do exactly that - given input key it will map it to output value (say, 128bit -> 128bit)

Link: http://www.atmel.com/zh/cn/Images/article_random_number.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a name for those class of random functions, but I believe the Mersenne Twister (commonly MT19937) is supposed to guarantee identical results no matter the platform or implementation.

Generally speaking, there's no guarantee that any given hash or random function will return the same results on different platform.  That seems to be an implementation detail of the algorithm in question.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the question, I don't think he's asking about hash functions, but PRNGs. (I could be wrong.)

A Pseudo-Random Number Generator -- most computer RNGs are PRNGs -- generates a fixed sequence of numbers based upon the "seed".

All the C and C++ RNGs (except for one) are PRNGs.

See the [<random>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) docs.

Comment: I think all those random generators can return a sequence of random numbers, but what If I try to retrieve the 100,000,000th number then the 99,999,999th number? I need an algorithm able to always generate the same result for a given key without having to go through all the preceding numbers.

Comment: Can you explain how the question "what If I try to retrieve the 100,000,000th number then the 99,999,999th number?" is related to the requirements above? Why would you be interested in retrieving any number from the psuedo-random sequence other than the first? When you say "without having to go through all the preceding numbers" it makes me scratch my head.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net Random class has a constructor that takes a seed. For a given seed (what you call "given integer key"), you should get the same "random" number in return. In this way it is like a hash.

```
    int seed = 101;
    Random r = new Random(seed);  //use same seed
    int rInt = r.Next(0, 100);    //can specify a range
    Console.WriteLine(rInt);
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx#Same

Comment: Hi, this can work during prototyping, but is there some sort of algorithm which achieves the same effect without any memory allocation? I must avoid any memory allocation during calls to the random number retrieval.

Comment: Considering you always want the same value returned for the same key, could you simply create a static data structure of key value pairs for the complete set of valid keys? Is the set small enough? Do you have enough memory for this?

Comment: Creating a hash map is not an optimal solution either as different seeds can be retrieved during execution and would then result in even higher allocations.